# Why does this Material UI Select component generate warnings?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following example jsfiddle:

```
const {
  Select,
  MenuItem, 
  InputLabel,
  FormControl
} = MaterialUI;


const {useState} = React;


function App() {    
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1); 
  
  function onChange(event) {   
        setValue(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
    <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
      <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Profile</InputLabel>
         <Select
          value={value}
          label="Profile"
          onChange={onChange}
          >          
            <MenuItem value="1">Test</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="2">Test</MenuItem>
            
      </Select>
      <div>value: {value}</div>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render( < App / > );
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/derekgreer/yd96usja/)

This produces the following:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.

How do you get the generated `<li>` elements to have a key?

Answer (score 1):

As the link says `Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed.` Put more simply this creates a relationship between the component and the DOM to ensure that React re-renders correctly.

The issue you have here is you have the repeating `<MenuItem>`. Without a key, it isn't uniquely identified to React. To add a key, you simply add a key property to the component `<MenuItem key="someKey">`

You can decide how you want to generate unique keys, but for simple things like this you could just give it a key property and add a number.

For an actual an application you would want to create an array, and assign a value and id, then loop through with `map()` or you could just use index.

Example:

```
const menuItems = [
  { 
    value: 'Test',
    id: 'someUniqueId1'
  },
  { 
    value: 'Test',
    id: 'someUniqueId2'
  }
]

return (
  <div>
  <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Profile</InputLabel>
       <Select
        value={value}
        label="Profile"
        onChange={onChange}
        >          
          {menuItems.map(item => {
             <MenuItem key={item.id}>{item.value}</MenuItem>
          })}
          OR
          {menuItems.map((item, index) => {
             <MenuItem key={index}>{item.value}</MenuItem>
          })}
        
    </Select>
    <div>value: {value}</div>
    </FormControl>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: While I'm familiar with the underlying React warning and its cause from React's perspective, I do appreciate you providing background information for others.  The question, however, is really about how to get Material UI to propagate the key and thus far it does not appear that it does.  I've got a slightly modified version of your example at https://jsfiddle.net/derekgreer/9ju7hg10/ which still produces the warning.  Based on the MenuItem docs, I'm not seeing a supported key property.  If you would, please update your answer with a working jsfiddle.net link.

Comment: @DerekGreer The warning doesn't happen in this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/menuitem-key-53sy3q) using equivalent code to your jsfiddle.

Comment: @DerekGreer I think your jsfiddle was working inappropriately due to mixing the production bundle of MUI with the development bundle for React. If you use the development bundle for both, the warning goes away in jsfiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/bug7f2dL/.

Comment: @DerekGreer interesting and thanks for sharing that. I had copied your code and started my own fiddle to make sure the error left, but indeed with your fiddle I still get the error. Sounds like Ryan Cogswell has figured out the issue? As far as your other question I'm unaware of any official ways to make React or libraries like Material UI generate a key for you. I've read into some things about ideas on how to make keys, but never have seen anything where it's done implicitly.

Comment: Great find!  Very interesting that the combination matters.  Also I find it very interesting that Material UI doesn't generate a key property for the rendered <li> elements whether you attempt to include a key or not, but for some reason doesn't trigger the warning.  Guess it's some bypassing of that section of React code.

Comment: @DerekGreer You seem to have a misunderstanding of how keys work in React. `MenuItem` only renders a [single `<li>` element](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.8.3/packages/mui-material/src/MenuItem/MenuItem.js#L199) so the warning does not apply. I recommend reviewing this part of the React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thanks for this.  You're correct that I did have a misunderstanding of how keys work and it makes sense that individual MenuItems wouldn't trigger that warning. That being the case, I wonder why the mis-match of prod vs. dev makes a difference.